# r Shiny: Cannot resolve error when using dateInput with shinjs::toggleState

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I am using R version 3.6.2, and I am encountering an error when using dateInput within shinyjs::toggleState. The error for my code doesn't generate for other input data types. I feel I am making an error in some stage of the date conversion. I attempted few different options and still unable to resolve the issue. Any support to resolve the issue is highly appreciated. The snippets of UI and Server code from my attempts are below.

**Attempt 1**

*UI*

```
 shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
    selectInput("player_names_output","Select Player",choices = c("Player 1","Player 2","Player 3")),
     dateInput("session_date", "Training Date",value = as.Date(NA),format = "%d-%m-%Y"),
    actionButton("submit_button","Submit"),
```

*Server*

```
   observe({
      shinyjs::toggleState("submit_button", !is.null(input$player_names) && input$player_names != "" && !is.null(input$session_date) && input$session_date != "")
    })
```

> Error in charToDate: character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

**Attempt 2**

*UI*

```
shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
selectInput("player_names_output","Select Player",choices = c("Player 1","Player 2","Player 3")),
 dateInput("session_date", "Training Date",value = as.Date(NA),format = "%d-%m-%Y"),
actionButton("submit_button","Submit"),
```

Server

```
 observe({
      shinyjs::toggleState("submit_button", !is.null(input$player_names) && input$player_names != "" && 
   !is.null(as.Date(input$session_date,format = "%d-%m-%Y")) && as.Date(input$session_date,format = "%d- 
     %m-%Y") != "")
    })
```

> Error in charToDate: character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for `as.Date` in the ui, pass the format of the date to the `format` argument of `dateInput`. Then pass either a date object to value or a character string in the same format passed to the `format` argument.

Put this in your ui:

```r
shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
selectInput("player_names_output","Select Player",choices = c("Player 1","Player 2","Player 3")),
dateInput("session_date", "Training Date",value = Sys.Date(), format = "dd-mm-yyyy"),  actionButton("submit_button","Submit")
```

The error occurs because you are trying to compare a date with a string in the server. You can only compare like with like. Place the `input$session_date` inside an `as.character()` call. Furthermore, the date input will be a date object by default so no need to use `as.Date` in the server.

Updated server:

```r
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    shinyjs::toggleState("submit_button", condition = !is.null(input$player_names) & input$player_names != "" &
                           !is.null(input$session_date) & as.character(input$session_date) != "")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: @Mr.Rover: Thank you very much for the reply. Unfortunately, I still get the same error (Error in charToDate: character string is not in a standard unambiguous format) to the shinyjs::toggleState.

Comment: @Mr.Rover: I was able to resolve the error. Thank you very much for the support extended. Very much appreciated.